# How to set default country flag when entering mobile number

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add default country flag(india) in my select box.
I'm using Angular 4 international phone prefix input box. But I'm not getting how to set the default value. They shared the docs on github as

@Input() locale
An ISO 639-1 language code can be provided to set available language: es: Spanish, en: English

@Input() defaultCountry
An ISO 639-1 country code can be provided to set default country selected.

I've tried this but it is not working.

```
<int-phone-prefix formControlName="myPhone" [locale]="'hi'" [defaultCountry]="in"> </int-phone-prefix>
```

I'm using ng4-intl-phone package,
Please help me sort this issue

Comment: Please add which package you are using for the same

Comment: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defaultCountry without attribute binding as `in` is your string not dynamic content so try this

```
<int-phone-prefix formControlName="myPhone" [locale]="'hi'" defaultCountry="in"> </int-phone-prefix>
```

or

```
<int-phone-prefix formControlName="myPhone" [locale]="'hi'" [defaultCountry]="'in'"> </int-phone-prefix>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
HTML
``` 
                <mat-form-field class="pd-mat-form-field-class" hideRequiredMarker>
                <label class="pd-mat-custom-label">{{"CELL_1" | translate }}</label>
                <mat-label></mat-label>
                <input ng2TelInput #intlInput 
                [ng2TelInputOptions]="cell1TelInput" 
                (hasError)="hasError1($event)" 
                (ng2TelOutput)="getNumberCellNo1($event)" 
                (intlTelInputObject)="cell1telInputObject($event)" 
                (countryChange)="onCell1CountryChange($event)" 
                type="text" 
                maxlength=14  class="pd-mat-form-input-margin"  
                matInput  name="cell_no1"
                formControlName = "cellnumber1" required>
              `</mat-form-field>`
```

Javascript
` 
```

cell1TelInput = {
initialCountry: 'za', //default country
autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
nationalMode :true,
customPlaceholder: function(selectedCountryPlaceholder) {
  return 'Example : ' + selectedCountryPlaceholder;
}

  if (response.userCellNumbers[0] && response.userCellNumbers[0].cell_no) {
            this.cellnumber1 = response.userCellNumbers[0].cell_no;  
            this.cell_code1.setNumber(this.cellnumber1)     
          }

 getNumberCellNo1(e:any)
  {
    this.cell_code1.setNumber(e) 
    this.cellnumber1=e
  }

  public onCell1CountryChange(e: any) {
    this.cellnumber1DialCode =  e.dialCode;
    this.cell1TelInput.initialCountry = e.iso2
    this.cell_code1.setNumber("") 
  }

  public cell1telInputObject(obj) {
    this.cell_code1=obj
  }

  hasError1(event: any): void {
    if (!event && this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1 ) {
    this.uploadForm.get('cellnumber1').setErrors(['invalid_cell_phone', true]);
    }
    }

  if (this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1) {
      this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1 = this.cellnumber1
      this.cellNumbers.push( {"cell_no": this.uploadForm.value.cellnumber1.replace(/\s/g, ""), "cell_type": 1});
    }`

```
    hasError() is used for validation
    The getNumber() will give you the country code and number as +919843133490.
    The setNumber() will set the country flag and place the number in input field.
    ng2TelInputOptions is used to initialize data

    Hope it helped. Any further queries can be asked.
````